# How to integrate react DnD with react fullcalendar?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I have the following simple demo for a drag and drop component using React DnD plugin.

**Card.js** (DropSource)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';


const ItemTypes = {
    CARD: 'card'
};

const cardSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
      return {  };
    }
}

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
       connectDragSource : connect.dragSource(),
       connectDragPreview: connect.dragPreview(),
       isDragging : monitor.isDragging()
    } 
}

class Card extends Component {

    render() {
        const { connectDragSource , isDragging } = this.props;

        return connectDragSource( 
          <div style={{
            opacity : isDragging ? 0.5 : 1,
            height: '50px',
            width: '50px',
            backgroundColor: 'orange',
          }}>
            &#9822;
          </div>
        );
      }

}

export default DragSource(ItemTypes.CARD, cardSource , collect)(Card);
```

**Box.js** (Droptarget)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DropTarget } from 'react-dnd';


const boxTarget = {
    canDrop(props) {

    },

    drop(props) {

    }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
      connectDropTarget: connect.dropTarget(),
      isOver: monitor.isOver(),
      canDrop: monitor.canDrop()
    };
}

const ItemTypes = {
    CARD: 'card'
};


class Box extends Component {

    render() {
        const { connectDropTarget, isOver, canDrop } = this.props;

        return connectDropTarget(
          <div style={{
            position: 'relative',
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            background: canDrop ? '#ff0000' : '#eee'
          }}>
              { this.props.children }
          </div>
        );
    }

}

export default DropTarget(ItemTypes.CARD, boxTarget, collect)(Box);
```

**simpleDrag.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { DragDropContext } from 'react-dnd';
import HTML5Backend from 'react-dnd-html5-backend';
import CARD from './card';
import BOX from './box';

class simpleDrag extends Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <BOX />
                <CARD/>
            </div>    
        ); 
    }

} 

export default DragDropContext(HTML5Backend)(simpleDrag);
```

And then ofcourse i use the simpleDrag element in my app.js to render and i have a working DnD example , now my question is how can i use DnD along site fullcalender.js ? I.E. say i want to make each day cell in the full calender a dropable target how do i do that ?

[Fullcalender.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fullcalendar-reactwrapper)

[React DnD](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-overview.html)

The above code can be found in my github repo [HERE](https://github.com/gautamz07/action-snowball).

Comment: You can take insights from [`react-big-calendar`](https://github.com/intljusticemission/react-big-calendar). This calendar is inspired by Fullcalendar and already have integration with `react-dnd`. [Here's a working](http://intljusticemission.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html) drag & drop demo of `react-big-calendar` + there's the source.

Comment: @JordanEnev thanks , that what i was looking into , but i wanted to know how to drag and drop an external event , trying to do that right now.

Comment: [Here's a working example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging-demo) with an external event(but using jQuery draggable). So according to the example, you have to find a way to get `DropSource` dom node element and add to it a `data` attribute with some Fullcalendar properties. Therefore on successful drop (Fullcalendar `drop`  handler), you have to remove `DropSource`  somehow, because it will be added to the Fullcalendar.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @Dupocas buddy i did't , iam sure there is a solution , but i've not worked on it

Comment: Did you look into using Fullcalendar's [External Event Dragging](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/external-dragging)? Check out their live demo. Perhaps this supplies the "make each day call in the full calendar a dropable target" functionality you are looking for. If so, I could try to write an answer that integrates with your solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate `fullcalendar` and `react-dnd` using the `ThirdPartyDraggable` interface provided by `fullcalendar` ([docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/third-party-dragging)).

However, it is important to notice that `fullcalendar` reacts to mouse events to implement its drag and drop. `react-dnd` provides the a `html5-backend`, but they don't play together nicely as the HTML5 Drag and Drop API disables mouse events in favour of drag events.

You should thus use an alternative backend that uses those mouse events. E.g. [this one](http://zyzo.github.io/react-dnd-mouse-backend/).

I implemented a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-dnd-9r81w) with an example implementation.

Answer (score 0):

for the record, hooks (which React is about in functional components) cannot be used in class-based components (https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html).

You might want to consider rewriting your Card and Box as RFCs instead of RCCs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use package dnd

> npm i react-beautiful-dnd
> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkzC5.png)